# Replace Null values of a column with its average in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any function in Spark which can calculate the mean of a column in a DataFrame by ignoring null/NaN? Like in R, we can pass an option such as na.rm=TRUE.

When I apply avg() on a column with a NaN, I get NaN only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
df.na.drop(Seq("c_name")).select(avg(col("c_name")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe without the null values in all the columns so that column mean can be calculated in the next step

```
removeAllDF = df.na.drop()
```

Create a list of columns in which the null values have to be replaced with column means and call the list "columns_with_nas"

Now iterate through the list "columns_with_nas" replace all the null values with the calculated mean values

```
for x in columns_with_nas:
    meanValue = removeAllDF.agg(avg(x)).first()[0]
    print(x, meanValue)
    df= df.na.fill(meanValue, [x])
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work for me in Spark 2.1.0:

```
In [16]: mydesc=[{'name':'Fela', 'age':46},
                {'name':'Menelik','age':None},
                {'name':'Zara','age':39}]
In [17]: mydf = sc.parallelize(mydesc).toDF()
In [18]: from pyspark.sql.functions import avg
In [20]: mydf.select(avg('age')).collect()[0][0]
Out[20]: 42.5
```